# Is there a way to extract a specific sentence from a word document based on keywords?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a single sentence from several heavily formatted word documents (. docx,. doc,. rtf).
Sentence example: This attachment consists of pages No. 1 to “number of pages, different for each document.”.

I am able to extract the first part of the sentence, but I am unable work out how to extract the sentence with the number at the end.

**I use this code to read the .doc and .rtf documents**

**I borrowed this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274601/opening-a-ms-word-file-in-pywin32/16616627) conversation*

```
word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
doc_path = os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'Users', 'user', 'Desktop', 'Testing','RTFexample.rtf')
doc = word.Documents.Open(doc_path)

for p in doc.paragraphs:
    print(p.Range.Text)
doc.Close()
word.Quit
```

**and this to read the .docx documents**

```
document = Document('DOCXexample.docx')

for p in document.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: "but the number at the end I am unable work out." -- Please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: I am Sorry It was a poor choise of word. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below code snippet:**

```
import textract
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def sentence_finder(text: str, words: list) -> list:
  sentences=sent_tokenize(text)
  return [sentence for sentence in sentences if any(word.lower() in word_tokenize(sentence.lower()) for word in words)]

# text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
text = textract.process("sample_doc.docx").decode("utf-8")

words = ['discovered', 'unfortunately']

extracted_sentences = sentence_finder(text, words)

for sent in extracted_sentences:
  print(sent)


'''
Output:

You've discovered the evil laboratory of Dr. Boolean, and you've found that the vile doctor is transforming your fellow rabbit kin into terrifying rabbit-zombies!
Unfortunately, once an access code is used it cannot be used again.
'''
```

**Notes:**
Please execute below commands in terminal to download basic nltk files.

1. `import nltk`
2. `nltk.download('punkt')`

Comment: @Pancake Update the full code snippet. Hope it will works for you. Please let me know if it not worked.